# Does "Not Connected" state of Bluetooth/Wi-Fi drain my iPhone battery?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, battery, bluetooth

As we all know in iOS 11 there are three states for Bluetooth and Wi-Fi buttons in Control Centre: **`Off`**, **`Not Connected`**, and **`On`**.

[image]

1. I'd like to know whether **`Not Connected`** state drains my iPhone battery or not?
2. And how to turn off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi completely via Control Centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes** it does!

1. It would be wrong to say that **Not Connected** status *does not* drain the battery at all. However, the drain rate is significantly less as the device is not connected to any access point (for Wi-Fi) and Bluetooth radio doesn't consume much battery anyways.
2. In iOS 11, it is not possible to *completely* turn off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth from the Control Centre. It could only be done from within the Settings app.

Quoting from the Apple Support document, [Use Bluetooth and Wi-Fi in Control Center with iOS 11](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208086)

> ### About Wi-Fi and Bluetooth
>
> In iOS 11 and later, when you toggle the Wi-Fi or Bluetooth buttons in Control Center, your device will immediately disconnect from Wi-Fi and Bluetooth accessories. Both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth will continue to be available, so you can use these important features:
>
> - AirDrop
> - AirPlay
> - Apple Pencil
> - Apple Watch
> - Continuity features, like Handoff and Instant Hotspot
> - Instant Hotspot
> - Location Services

Thus, it is apparent that battery draining will still happen. However, the device disconnects from Wi-Fi access point and Bluetooth accessory.